# Piecemaker flash slider clipped by it's container?

Tags: html, css, flash, slider, overflow

I am implementing the flash slider, Piecemaker, for the first time in my latest project. I've got a problem with it's animation being cropped by the width and height of its container, and I cannot for the life of me work out how to let it overflow outside its container during animations.

There is also a weird problem I've just noticed that the top of the slider gets clipped off for some reason?

Can anyone who's worked with piecemaker, or something similar, or a css ninja see what the problem is?

Here is the demo as it is at the moment - [Link](http://qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/Bohio/index_piecemaker.html)

Answer (score 0):

The clipping is due to the shadow or transparency in the images you are using here is trick i have discovered...

In your XML file settings if you are using like (This is exact image dimensions you are using)

```
<imageWidth>830</imageWidth>
<imageHeight>350</imageHeight>
```

the in your HTML document use these settings, you have to give some area to display shadows using this

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
AC_FL_RunContent(
    'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0',
    'width', '960px',
    'height', '420px',
    'src', 'piecemaker',
    'quality', 'high',
    'pluginspage', 'http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_de',
    'align', 'left',
    'play', 'true',
    'loop', 'true',
    'scale', 'noscale',
    'wmode', 'transparent',
    'devicefont', 'false',
    'id', 'piecemaker',
    'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
    'name', 'piecemaker',
    'menu', 'true',
    'allowFullScreen', 'false',
    'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
    'movie', 'piecemaker',
    'salign', ''
    ); //end AC code
</script>
```

So i have used exact pixel width and length and also used wmode to transparent
Hope it helps a lot